# How to ignore NaN's in my data?

Tags: matlab, nan

Is there any way to ignore the NaN in the functions?

I want to get the eig value Ignoring the NaN because the function eig doesn't deal with NaN

I have matrix NxM and it contains NaN values I have to apply the function eig on it but this function doesn't work with NaN values so either I will delete the NaN or if there is a function to do it Directly Like (nanmax it gives the maximum value ignoring NaN)

Comment: You would need to add a bit more detail - how do you want your function (perhaps `eig`) to ignore NaN values? Do you want it to ignore every row that contains a NaN? Or every column? Or perhaps you'd like it to treat every NaN value as a default value such as zero. It's not possible to just "remove" NaNs in an unspecified way, otherwise what you'd end up with might not be an actual array.

Comment: Define "Get rid of". You have a matrix, and you want to find eigen values. Some values are `NaN`, How you are going to deal with tme? Want to replace them by zero? I think it depends on the problem and the way you need to handle `NaN` values. You cannot just remove them from matrix withoit putting a new value in their place.

Comment: @SamRoberts The same feedback 37 seconds faster than me :-)

Comment: Sorry I have matrix NxM and it contains NaN values
I have to apply the function eig on it but this function doesn't work with NaN values so either I will delete the NaN or if there is a function to do it Directly Like (nanmax it gives the maximum value ignoring NaN)

Comment: Again - you need to add more detail, and define what you mean by "delete the NaN". You can't just remove the NaN values, or you will potentially not be left with anything that is an array at all. So you might either want to delete the NaN *and replace them with something else*, or to delete all rows containing NaNs, or delete all columns containing NaNs. Which is it?

Comment: Additionally, as @woodchips has pointed out, to compute eigenvalues your array must be square (i.e. NxN, not NxM).

Comment: And finally no, there is no equivalent of `nanmax` like `naneig`. The concept doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but there is NO magic way to just ignore NaN elements in a matrix to then compute the eigenvalues. You need ALL of the elements in an array to compute the eigenvalues. Tools to check for an NaN or delete the NaNs as others have suggested are simply no use. If you simply delete an element of an array, the array would no longer be square. So MATLAB turns the array into a vector, which is a completely different thing! And converting a NaN into a zero is highly unlikely to yield meaningful eigenvalues for an array.

Nor are tools like nanmean useful, which do a very simple thing. (Nanmean can do its work because it computes the mean of each column, where the NaNs are simply ignored. It just sums the non-NaN elements, then divides by the number of nan-NaNs.)

And finally, if you have an NxM matrix that is not square, it is meaningless to compute the eigenvalues. Eigenvalues are only defined for square matrices. Perhaps you are thinking about singular values, or perhaps you are trying to do principle components. In either of those cases, you will still need the full matrix, unless you intend to simply delete all the rows or columns that have nans in them.

There is no free lunch. You will need to determine the entire matrix to compute the eigenvalues of that matrix. At the very least, you need to rethink your problem, since it is meaningless to try to do as you have asked.

Comment: Down voting this response because I tell the person the truth?